# How to create a loop from this code?

Tags: python, logic

I have a python routine which puts PDF pages in booklet spread order. I'm trying to improve the code: there's a bit where I'm doing almost the same thing twice. When I write out the iteration, it works, but when I try to make it more general with more loops, it doesn't. The code puts two PDF pages onto a larger PDF page.

```
# For each side of the sheet, we must create a PDF page,
# take two source pages and place them differently, then close the page.
# If the source page number is 0, then move on without drawing.
    Sides = len(imposedOrder) / pagesPerSide
    count = 0
    for n in range(Sides):
        Quartz.CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, sheetSize)
        if imposedOrder[count]:
            page = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentGetPage(source, imposedOrder[count])
            Quartz.CGContextSaveGState(writeContext)
            Quartz.CGContextConcatCTM(writeContext, Quartz.CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, Quartz.kCGPDFMediaBox, leftPage, 0, True))
            Quartz.CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
            Quartz.CGContextRestoreGState(writeContext)
        count += 1  

        if imposedOrder[count]:
            page = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentGetPage(source, imposedOrder[count])
            Quartz.CGContextSaveGState(writeContext)
            Quartz.CGContextConcatCTM(writeContext, Quartz.CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, Quartz.kCGPDFMediaBox, rightPage, 0, True))
            Quartz.CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
            Quartz.CGContextRestoreGState(writeContext)
        count += 1  
        Quartz.CGContextEndPage(writeContext)
```

So the only bit that is different each time is whether we use leftPage or rightPage.

Here's the version that DOESN'T work:

```
count = 0
for n in range(Sides):
    Quartz.CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, sheetSize)
    for nn in range (1, pagesPerSide+1):
        if nn%2 == 1:
            position = leftPage
        else:
            position = rightPage
        if imposedOrder[count]:
            page = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentGetPage(source, imposedOrder[count])
            Quartz.CGContextSaveGState(writeContext)
            Quartz.CGContextConcatCTM(writeContext, Quartz.CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, Quartz.kCGPDFMediaBox, position, 0, True))
            Quartz.CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
            Quartz.CGContextRestoreGState(writeContext)
        count += 1
    Quartz.CGContextEndPage(writeContext)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work' ? can you give me the output or the error message ? Also maybe explain what `imposedOrder` is ;)

Comment: What's the reason for starting at 1 instead of 0 in `range (1, pagesPerSide)` ?

Comment: `Quartz.CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, sheetSize)` should be in the inner loop.

Comment: 1. It doesn't work: I just get a blank PDF of one page. imposedOrder is an array of page numbers in the order that they need to be placed in.


2. Ah: should be (1, pagesPerSide+1), but still doesn't help.


3. No: BeginPage refers to the bigger page that I am putting two PDFs onto.

Comment: I don't see the answer yet, but I do see an improvement: `for position in [leftPage, rightPage]:`

Comment: Is this line in both versions? Not shown in second one. `Sides = len(imposedOrder) / pagesPerSide`

Comment: In the unrolled-loop version, try using `position` instead of the literal `leftPage` and `rightPage`. Does it make any difference? Perhaps there's something weird about those objects.

Comment: Yes, that line is in both.  Thanks for the improvement: though ideally I'd be able to generalise the code to put n pages on the sheet. But that's for another day..

Comment: position, leftPage and rightPage are lists. I've tried using deepcopy to define position, too, but that also didn't change anything. I'll try your suggestion.